# Regarding giving credit to the source of inspiration of your answer.

Tags: discussion, answers, user-accounts, hyperlinks

If I answer a question whose answer was inspired by a similar question answered by someone else then should I credit that user's name or link to the original question in my answer?

Comment: I'd say, do both.

Comment: I think there have been many instances of similar appropriate attributions to *commenters* who preceded an answerer with a key observation in comments below a question they've answered.  I commend your for taking such inspiration into account!

Comment: Just a cautionary note, however.  If you find yourself answering a question extremely similar to a question answered by someone else at a different point in time, then I would seriously consider whether the questions is a duplicate of that other answered question, and if so, it should be closed as one, and not answered.

Comment: And by "duplicate" I don't mean a "word-for-word" copy.  Most on this site would consider, e.g., the question "How to solve for $x$ when $2x -4 = 3y$," and the question "Solve for y:  $5y+1=7x$" as "duplicates", in that the steps required to solve both of them are identical, just the numbers are changed.

Answer (score 14):

Unlike with [attribution](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), where you have to supply

> the name of the creator and attribution parties, a copyright notice, a license notice, a disclaimer notice, and a link to the material. CC licenses prior to Version 4.0 also require you to provide the title of the material if supplied, and may have other slight differences.

<sub>(copyright, license and disclaimer notice are already covered by the Stack Exchange framework)</sub>

there are no hard-and-fast rules for *inspiration*. However, as Gerry Myerson says in the comment, why not do both? E.g.

> As demonstrated by user [@Rhaldryn](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/116321/rhaldryn) in an answer to [this question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29469/228959) ...

It's not that much more work to type, compared to the amount of work the original author has put into their answer. Also, if the original question/answer ever gets deleted, you might still have a working link to the author.

Comment: Not only it is "not that much more work", it is also nice, and potentially useful.